# How to manipulate a JavaScript array passed to a function without changing the original argument array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I would like to work with an array passed to a function while leaving the original array untouched. Here is a simple example of the problem.

```
function whyDoesArrChange(arr) {
   var newArr = arr;
   newArr.push(4);

   return arr;
 }
 
 console.log(whyDoesArrChange([1,2,3]));
// OUT: [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like only `newArr` to be changed, but the `arr` (from the arguments) returns the pushed value as well (returns `[1,2,3,4]`). How can I avoid this?

Comment: The answer is going to depend upon whether the elements in the array need to be untouched as well.  As Marcos Casagrande has already suggested, you can use slice to generate a subset of the original array.  Doing so, will copy any objects in that array by reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When passing an array to a function, the value of that array is a reference, you have to clone it to break the reference.

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

**1 -** Using [.slice();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example)

```
var newArr = arr.slice();
```

**2 -** Using [.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example)

```
var newArr = arr.concat([]);
```

**3 -** Using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) & [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
var newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

You can check more ways and see how they perform in this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-copy/38) I found.

Comment: Can anyone please explain a bit more why changing newArr also changes arr? Why is .slice() so special that THAT doesn't also change arr? Thank you, I'm learning a lot here.

Comment: *Why is .slice() so special that THAT doesn't also change arr? Thank you, I'm learning a lot here*. `slice` creates a new array that's why it doesnt change arr.

Comment: And about your first question, check this: https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600  since it's little to broad to explain it here.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, when you use (=) to assign a value from a variable to another one, you're just passing the entire variable, so each time one or another changes, the other will change too.

According to your question, the best way that works for me is using the native .slice() JavaScript method to the arrays object. For your code:

```
function whyDoesArrChange(arr) {
    var newArr = arr.slice();
    newArr.push(4);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: "In JavaScript when you use (=) to assign a value from a variable to another one, you're just passing the entire variable, so each time one or another changes". That's not always true, `x = 4; y = x; y = 5;` will not change x. That's because x is assigned with a primitive value. In case of non-primitive values like Object or Array, the assignment is by reference, where each variable is linked to the same data in memory, therfore changing one, will change the other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight, I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1):

While Marcos' answer is correct, no doubt. There are more pure Array functions that can be used (A pure function is a function that doesn't alter data outside of its' scope).

Usually, if you'd like to do multiple actions on the array, I would go with Marcos' answer and then do those changes as usual. But when that's not the case, the following information may be useful:

1. Adding: `arr.concat([1]);`
2. Subarray (i to j): `arr.slice(i, j + 1);`
3. Removing (i to j): `arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(j + 1));`

Also, `filter` and `map` are pure function that will not alter the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because reference types (arrays and objects) can get modified inside functions when passed as arguments, while primitive types (numbers, strings, booleans etc.) don't.

You can make a shallow copy the array with `.slice()` and work on that array, or return a new array with the `.concat` method.

```
function whyDoesArrChange(arr) {
   return arr.concat(4);
 }
```